# Magento 2.2.5 - Table catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 not being automatically generated

Tags: magento2, search, reindex

**Summary**
The exception log becomes bloated with "main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1' doesn't exist". sometimes reindexing cycle is working properly.but sometime it's not generated/rename from catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp folder. If we check in database, table is not exist but if you try to create, it will show table is already exists. and if we rename 'catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp' table to 'catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1', it will show table is already exist. If you try to delete it, it will show table is not exist

**Environment**
Magento 2.2.5 and possibly earlier versions
PHP 7.0
Custom extensions are installed but are up to date with magento version

**Steps to reproduce**
1.Check that cron jobs are set up and running
2.Check exceptions log

**Expected result**
On indexing cycle, no errors should occur.

**Actual result**
On indexing cycle, error "main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1' doesn't exist" appears.

Answer (score 4):

I just fixed same issue on my server. Access to server and run:

("Magento" is my database name)

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/Magento
rm -rf catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1.ibd
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

After that, the table **catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1** will be regenerated.

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Wondering if it was really necessary to delete the database file? Seems a bit of a nuclear option, wouldn't the reindex have repopulated catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 anyway?

Comment: @DougMcLean incase it was keeping you up at night I just ran the reindex without and it fixed the issue

Comment: It helped. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

you need to run form your Magento root
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
and you need to setup Cron jobs